# How to safely access and modify an array while multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to manipulate a variable of type `array of record`, by multiple threads, and I'm not sure whether what i did is the right way, or if there is a better and safer method?

I declared a `boolean` variable as a lock, and when some thread want to access the array it waits till the lock is off, then activate the lock, and when done, unlock it and let others have access.

The code for this is declared in the implementation section

```
...
implementation

var Data : array of TData;
var Data_Lock:Boolean=false;

procedure Lock_Data();
begin
   while Data_Lock = True do
       sleep(1);
   Data_Lock := True;
end;

procedure UnLock_Data();
begin
    Data_Lock := False;
end;

procedure ClearAll();
begin
    Lock_Data();
    SetLength( Data, 0 );
    UnLock_Data();
end;
....
```

The entire project is still not complete. For now this seems to work but i don't have any knowledge of how these things work at the core, and whether there would be a problem if two threads start at the exact same time?

Answer (score 5):

Your locking approach is not thread safe and it will not protect your data.

With multiple threads you have to consider that any particular thread execution can be interrupted at any time and that another thread can "jump" in and access some variable in between.

That means following scenario is possible (simplified):

```
Data_Lock is False
Thread A enters Lock_Data()
Thread A checks Data_Lock -> False and skips the loop
Thread B enters Lock_Data()
Thread B checks Data_Lock -> False and skips the loop (Thread A didn't have the chance to set it to True yet)
Thread A continues -> sets Data_Lock to True and gains access to protected data
Thread B continues -> sets Data_lock to True and gains access to protected data while Thread A is still using that data
```

---

You can use `TCriticalSection` from `System.SyncObjs` instead.

```
var DataLock: TCriticalSection;

procedure ClearAll();
begin
  DataLock.Enter;
  try
    SetLength(Data, 0);
  finally
    DataLock.Leave;
  end;
end;
```

Since `TCriticalSection` is a class you need to create `DataLock` instance before you can use it and you need to free it when you no longer need it. For instance, you can do that in initialization/finalization section of a unit.

```
initialization
  DataLock := TCriticalSection.Create;

finalization  
  DataLock.Free;
end.
```

However, the better approach would be to wrap your data and critical section together in a class.